# How to build Google's protobuf in Windows using MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, protocol-buffers

I'm using Codeblocks as my IDE with MingGW. 
I'm trying to use google protocol buffers, 
but I'm having trouble building the protobuf.

The readme file for protobuf says:

> If you are using Cygwin or MinGW, 
>   follow the Unix installation instructions, above.

The Unix instructions says:

> To build and install the C++ Protocol Buffer runtime and  the Protocol
>   Buffer compiler (protoc) execute the following:
>   `$ ./configure
>   $ make 
>   $ make check 
>   $ make install`

I don't know how to perform these in Windows 
because "configure" is a Unix script and 
I don't know how to execute it, or the rest of the commands.

Can someone explain in more detail how 
I can build protobuf using MinGW on Windows?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

1. You need to install MSYS with mingw. This is a minimal unix-like shell environment that lets you configure/make most unix packages. Read the mingw docs on how to install that (either with mingw-get or the GUI installer).
2. Once you have installed MSYS, you should have a shortcut in your start menu, named "MinGW Shell". That opens a console with a bash.
3. Extract the source tarball to your MSYS home directory. I have mingw installed in "D:\prog", so the directory was "D:\prog\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\<username>". You can tell your MSYS username from the shell prompt. When done, you should have a directory "D:\prog\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\<username>\protobuf-2.4.1".
4. At the shell prompt, change to the protobuf directory:

   `cd protobuf-2.4.1`
5. Run the configure script (note the backquotes):

   `` ./configure --prefix=`cd /mingw; pwd -W` ``

   The `--prefix` paramater makes sure protobuf is installed in the mingw directory tree instead of the MSYS directories, so you can build outside the MSYS shell (e.g. with CodeBlocks...)
6. Run make:

   `make`
7. Install:

   `make install`
8. That's it. You should now be able to compile your project with protobuf.
   You should be able to:

   - call `protoc` from your project/makefiles
   - `#include <google/protobuf/message.h>` etc.
   - link with `-lprotobuf` or `-lprotobuf-lite`

HTH
Peter

Edit:
Bringing this a bit more up to date. I tried setting up a new PC with current versions of MinGW and protobuf 2.5.0, and these are the problems I had:

1. There is no "MinGW Shell" shortcut in the start menu.
   For some reason current MinGW installations fail to install that.
   But there is a `msys.bat` in `<Mingw home>\msys\1.0` which brings up a console with a bash. Create a shortcut to that batch file somewhere.
2. gcc does not work from the MSYS shell.
   I had to run a post-installation batch file manually and answer the questions there. This sets up fstab entries that mount the mingw directories in the MSYS environment.
   You need to run `<Mingw home>\msys\1.0\postinstall\pi.bat`
3. My Avira antivirus interfered with the protobuf compilation.
   It complained about the generated protoc.exe being a "TR/Crypt.XPACK.Gen" trojan and blocked acces to that file, resulting in a corrupted build.
   I got error messages saying something like `protoc:./.libs/lt-protoc.c:233: FATAL: couldn't find protoc.` when trying to start protoc.
   I had to disable the Avira realtime scanner and `make clean && make && make install` again

Edit #2:

This post has aged quite a bit, and mingw does not equal mingw anymore.
In this day and age, I would rather recommend MSYS2 which comes with a port of ArchLinux's pacman package manager, a recent, better-working (c++11 std::thread support!) mingw fork for both 32 and 64 bit, and a protobuf package that you just need to install and be good.

[Go here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) to download!

Hope this helps!
Peter

Comment: Ok, i did it, and it worked :), so thanx a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Peter: I tried following the steps you listed. When I run the './configure' command I get following error:     checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
' As a result, none of the make, make install commands work. For eg: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: Using MinGW I ran into this problem: tar: "Archive value 84224 is out of uid_t range 0..65535"

It turns out that cygwin has support for larger uid's. If you see this problem install cygwin and repeat the above instructions.

Comment: Wow. Never going back to Windows from Linux. What a mess Windows is.

Comment: This solution does not work with MinGW (32b), Win7 and versions of protobuf > 3.0.0. The `./configure` struggles to find the `zlib` library and the `make` fails as described in [issue 2089](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2089). For more details, see my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179693/build-protobuf-on-windows-with-mingw).

Answer (score 1):

In my case Peter's answer did not work completely, I used the latest MinGW 4.8.1 + the MSys distribution (selected both MSys packages in `mingw-get`).

My problem was that the prefix didn't really work, I could only find the files in `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local` . However, after copying the bin / include / libs folders to `c:\mingw,` the installation worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it by building protocol buffers using boost build.
That worked fine, I can provide a jamfile for protocol buffers.

What I still have problems with though is to extend boost build so it generates cpp source files from proto files, but that is another story.

Comment: Present-day versions of the protobuf source distribution (3.0.0-beta2) do not have a ./configure script, and `autoconf` fails; any chance of an updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

**LATEST ANSWER**

Here is an answer for the present-day versions of protobuf source distribution, for using protobuf for C++ language in Windows.
(My protobuf version is 21.4- **libprotoc 3.21.4**)

Referring to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9244456/14465779) by @peter-remmers

**Step 0:** Download protobuf [zip file from release page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v21.4). e.g. "protobuf-cpp-3.21.4.zip"

- Extract it to a path where you want protobuf to be installed.
- Add the "src" folder path to system's environment path variables. e.g. "C:\Path-To-Protobuf\protobuf-3.21.4\src"

**Step 1:** Download & install msys2: https://www.msys2.org/

Make sure to to do these:

- `pacman -Syu`
- Run "MSYS2 MSYS" from Start menu. Update the rest of the base packages with `pacman -Syu`
- `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`

**Step 2:** Add the mingw bin files' path to system's environment variables.

- e.g. it was "C:\Path-To-Msys2\msys2\mingw64\bin" and "C:\Path-To-Msys2\msys2\usr\bin"
- Confirm by Checking the g++ version: `g++ --version` in the terminal (e.g. Mine is 12.1.0)

**Step 3:** Setting Up C++ runtime with protobuf libraries:

- So, back **in msys2**, install protobuf's libraries: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-protobuf`. [Reference](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-protobuf)
- Now, change the directory to path where protobuf is installed in your system : e.g. cd "C:\Path-To-Protobuf\protobuf-3.21.4"
- Run the configure file of protobuf: `./configure`
- Run `make` (In case of any error with aclocal, etc. Try running `pacman -S autoconf`, then try again `make`)
- Run `make install`

**Step 4:**
That's it. You should now be able to compile your project with protobuf.

e.g. To compile a .proto file using protoc to cpp code & header files:

- Use: `protoc --cpp_out=$OUTDIR example.proto`
- Two files, a `pb.cc` & a `pb.h` file will be generated.
- Write a cpp code to use that header file and create objects, populate data, etc.
- Compile that cpp writer file from terminal/PowerShell like:

`g++ -I "C:\Path-To-Protobuf\protobuf-3.21.4\src" "Path-To-Code\writer.cpp" "Path-To-Code\example.pb.cc" -o "Path-To-Code\writer.exe" -L "C:\Path-To-Protobuf\protobuf-3.21.4\src\.libs" -lprotobuf -pthread`

("-pthread" is not really important at the end I guess.)

NOTE (The problem I had): Order of paths of e.g. mingw in system's environment variables list matters very much.