# protobuf linking errors with MingW

Tags: c++, mingw, protocol-buffers

Currently I am my writing cpp app on MingW which uses protobuf. But during compilation, it shows lots of linker errors, saying

> undefined reference to google::protobuf::internal

and

> undefined reference to google::protobuf::message.

I have already included `-L/path/to/lib/ -lprotobuf` in gcc.

But still not working..
Any input?

Comment: Are there any furhter headers you need to include?

Answer (score 0):

Make shure you followed the installtion stepps correctly: [How to build Google's protobuf in Windows using MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243816/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw)

Especially take a look at *5.*, `--prefix` part:

> The --prefix paramater makes sure protobuf is installed in the mingw
>   directory tree instead of the MSYS directories, so you can build
>   outside the MSYS shell

Comment: The linked resource is quite aged, so read it carefully.