# Install Protocol Buffers on Windows

Tags: java, windows, cygwin, mingw, protocol-buffers

I am unable to find clear instructions to install Google Protocol Buffers (including compiler) on Windows x64 platform.

I went through the instructions README file for compiler and source:

> For Compiler: To install, simply place this binary somewhere in your PATH

I added system variable to Path:

```
PROTOC 'C:\dev_tools\protoc-2.4.1-win32'
```

I am stuck on installing Protocol Buffers source using Cygwin. I tried following 
Unix instructions provided in the readme file:

> To build and install the C++ Protocol Buffer runtime and the Protocol
>   Buffer compiler (protoc) execute the following:
>
> ```
> $ ./configure
> $ make
> $ make check
> $ make install
> ```
>
> If `make check` fails, you can still install, but it is likely that
>   some features of this library will not work correctly on your system.
>   Proceed at your own risk.
>
> `make install` may require superuser privileges.
>
> For advanced usage information on configure and make, see INSTALL.txt.
>
> ** Hint on install location **
>
> By default, the package will be installed to /usr/local. However, on many platforms, /usr/local/lib is not part of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can add it, but it may be easier to just install to /usr> instead.  To do this, invoke configure as follows:
>
> ```
> ./configure --prefix=/usr
> ```

I get

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory'
```

Can some one provide clear and detailed steps to make this work?

## UPDATE

I switched to using MSYS/MINGW32 instead and 
I followed instructions given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243816/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw). Now I am stuck with following:

When I run the './configure' command I get following error:
**checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp

configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check'**

As a result, none of the make, make install commands work. For eg:

```
make: No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Comment: Amazing how bad the documentation is on installing this. It's pathetic.

Comment: 2019 and Google's documentation for setting up protocol buffers on windows is still awful.

Comment: 2020 and things haven't changed much.

Comment: almost 2022 tomorrow and not much better

Comment: I'm here at the end of 2023

Answer (score 28):

For installing proto buff in windows

Go to https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

Scroll down and download the zip for windows compatible

[image]

Once download the zip, extract it to C:/

Just copy the path, `C:\protoc-3.17.3-win64\bin` and set this as path to an environment variables

[image]

Hope, this helps!

Comment: This one helped me in Windows, thanks! By the way instead of the Path Variable you can always just run ./protoc as a binary from its destination.

Comment: When you cannot find protoc on the download page, then you just need to click " Show all 28 assets" under Assets.  You can only see protobuf downloads at the top.

Answer (score 27):

If you just want to compile ProtoBuf definitions, you can download [precompiled binaries of protoc for all platforms](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/) right on the ProtoBuf GitHub releases page.

They had precompiled binaries at least since 2015, but it's easy to overlook them in between the many downloads.

Comment: >> but it's easy to overlook them in between the many downloads. Yes!

Comment: Thanks a lot. ok! thats really is true! they are at the very end!

Comment: What if I want to have the runtime libraries? I think this isn't sufficient for the problem in the question.

Comment: @Subin_Sebastian: Just download one of the other packages, then. It's all there.

Comment: Prebuilt binaries not for C++.

Comment: @MorioBoncz Is it not in `protobuf-cpp-3.13.0.tar.gz` ? I didn't check, I just went by the name.

Comment: Please note my answer is about `protoc`, the protobuf compiler, as that is the binary I was missing on the machine of a team mate, and OP also seemingly was missing that one. The rest, just include it in your normal build process, as you have to link against the libraries anyway.

Comment: @FlorianSesser What about the protobuf libraries (libprotobuf). I am confused why protoc is made available as an exe, but not the libraries. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Lolo Maybe this helps: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf?tab=readme-ov-file#protobuf-runtime-installation

Comment: @FlorianSesser Unfortunately this is all about building the runtime lib from source. I am not sure why they only provide protoc as binaries.

Answer (score 18):

There is a whole documentation file for compiling protobuf on Windows :

- https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md#c-installation---windows
- https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md

You'll need 7-zip, Cmake and Visual Studio.

Anyway, one of the unexpected side-effects of using a Continuous Integration tool (like Travis or Appveyor) is that there is always a up-to-date and working build script available. I happen to always look at `appveyor.yml` and `travis_config.yml` files whenever they exists.

```
>>> git clone -b v3.1.0 https://github.com/google/protobuf.git 
>>> cd protobuf
>>> curl -L -o release-1.7.0.zip https://github.com/google/googlemock/archive/release-1.7.0.zip
>>> 7z x release-1.7.0.zip
>>> del /Q release-1.7.0.zip
>>> rename googlemock-release-1.7.0 gmock
>>> curl -L -o release-1.7.0.zip "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.7.0.zip"
>>> 7z x release-1.7.0.zip
>>> del /Q release-1.7.0.zip
>>> rename googletest-release-1.7.0 gtest
>>> move gtest gmock
>>> set generator=Visual Studio 12 Win64
>>> set vcplatform=x64
>>> mkdir build_msvc
>>> cd build_msvc
>>> cmake -G "%generator%" -Dprotobuf_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=%BUILD_DLL% -Dprotobuf_UNICODE=%UNICODE% ../cmake
>>> msbuild protobuf.sln /p:Platform=%vcplatform% || goto error
```

You'll need `curl` (`Git Bash` has it) as well as resolving paths for the `7z.exe` and `Msbuild.exe` executables.

I successfully managed to build the protobuf compiler on a Windows 10 x64 machine with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Does it work for `java` protobuf compiler installation too.. It seems you are giving solution for installing `c++` compiler

Comment: There is no java protobuf compiler : the compiler is in C++ and there is a java binding embedding the resulted runtime. I did not tested the Java binding since I'm not competent in Java & Maven

Answer (score 18):

Use [chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/protoc)

`choco install protoc`

Comment: this is literally the answer
(if you dont have chocolatey please do you a favor and get it it will save you hassle after hassle)

Answer (score 6):

Download protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip from

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v2.5.0

Then to install, simply place this binary somewhere in your PATH

Comment: Note that the binaries and other files are under the "Assets" section that is by default not expanded.  So click on the little down arrow next to Assets.

Answer (score 4):

I was build **protobuf v2.4.1 on Windows 10** as follows:

- git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git;
- cd protobuf;
- git checkout v2.4.1;
- cd vsprojects
- open protobuf.sln in Visual Studio 2019
- Press build solution and take many errors: min undefined and max undefined
  Add in file protobuf/stubs/common.h next code:

> ```
> #if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(min)
> #define min(a,b) __min(a,b)
> #define max(a,b) __max(a,b)
> #endif
> ```

- Press build solution and take error: *fatal error C1189: “#error:  hash_map is deprecated and will be REMOVED….*”
- Add compile definition **-D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS** solved problem
- Next I had error “*error C2664: "std::pair std::make_pair(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) noexcept”…*”
- In file src\google\protobuf\compiler\command_line_interface.cc I modified string “*proto_path_.push_back(make_pair< string, string >(virtual_path, disk_path));*” to “**proto_path_.push_back(make_pair(virtual_path, disk_path));**”
- Press build solution. All build succeed.(Tests projects not build without test framework)

  INSTALL:
- Run extract_includes.bat to copy all the public headers into a separate "include" directory (under the top-level package directory).
- Copy the contents of the include directory to wherever you want to put headers
- Copy protoc.exe wherever you put build tools
- copy libprotobuf.lib, libprotobuf-lite.lib, and libprotoc.lib wherever you put libraries.

Answer (score 4):

I installed it with chocolatey and it worked perfectly.

```
choco --install -y protoc
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using *vcpkg* tool on windows. Here is *step by step* [manual](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/installing-and-using-packages/).

Regarding *protobuf*, firstly check what options you have (in cmd):

*vcpkg search protobuf*

[image]

Next install the required package:
*vcpkg install protobuf:x64-windows-static*

Notice *x64-windows-static* after the colon - this is the *triplet*. Check *vcpkg help triplet* for all of them.

Then go to *your_path\vcpkg-master\packages\protobuf_x64-windows-static\*

[image]

Now you can set your environment variables.

Comment: you can install static and dynamic versions of the lib by omitting "-static" part

Answer (score 0):

Now protobuf is a NuGet package in Visual Studio. Just go get that.

Comment: Installing with vcpk give me this error `Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:273 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/protobuf/portfile.cmake:44 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:71 (include)


Error: Building package protobuf:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED`

Answer (score 0):

just easy [ref](https://chocolatey.org/packages/protoc)

```
choco install protoc --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

choco install protoc --pre worked for, make sure your in an elevated state.

this is the output when I ran protoc from gitbash

$ protoc
Usage: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\protoc\tools\bin\protoc.exe [OPTION] PROTO_FILES
Parse PROTO_FILES and generate output based on the options given:
-IPATH, --proto_path=PATH   Specify the directory in which to search for

adding it to my $path environment variables didn't work from me as expected.