# Installing pyCLD3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, protoc

I'm trying to install [pyCLD3](https://pypi.org/project/pycld3/) on Windows 10 (python 3.8.5):

`pip install pycld3` on Windows does not work (as expected, it's mentioned in the README file on their [Github](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pycld3)).

However, the instructions how to install it from Source are not clear, it only states that I need some prerequisites and gives an unclear [reference](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src) on how to install one of them (Protobuf), but not the others and not how to proceed to install pyClD3 itself.

[image]

I managed to install Protoc using Chocolatey consulting [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616033/install-protocol-buffers-on-windows), however, I'm not sure if that's how I should have done it and how to proceed next, i.e. what are the *Protobuf development headers* and where to find *libprotoc* library - is it the same thing as Protobuf/protoc?
As for g++, I have installed MinGW from [here](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/), but also confused what to do with it next.

Here is a snippet of what I get when I try to install pyCLD3 using pip:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pycld3
  Building wheel for pycld3 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
<...>
Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpcld3/pycld3.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\cld3/pycld3.obj -std=c++11
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
  pycld3.cpp
  C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1lgq4b5o\pycld3_11fb5b01d9d44711b4031f733ec7f6cc\src\cld_3/protos/feature_extractor.pb.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/port_def.inc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycld3
```

Comment: Hello, pycld3 maintainer here. [This appears to be an issue with protobuf installation.](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5868) Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You may try Msys2. I managed to compile pycld3 in Windows 10 with Python3.7.

### In Windows 10's cmd

- download `pycld3-0.20.tar.gz` from https://pypi.org/project/pycld3/#files, untar it and `cd` to that directory
- creatae a Py3.7 virtual environ (`py -3.7 -m venv venv`). (I dont know whether other Python versions work or not.)

### Msys2

- install msys2 `https://www.msys2.org/`
- start msys2 (`c:\msys64\msys2.exe`)
- update msys2: do a few `pacman -Syuu` as necessary
- install the toolchain (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb mingw-w64-x86_64-make`)
- install protoc (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-protobuf`, protoc installed by choco didnt work in my experiment but this protoc works)
- setup PATH (`export PATH=$PATH:/mingw64/bin/`)
- insert a `#include <math.h>` line before line 6 of `Python.h` (e.g `C:\Python\Python37\include\Python.h` in my case). This fixed the `_hypot` related errors.
- compile and install (go to the directory above, e.g. `cd /c/Users/xyz/Downloads/pycld3-0.20/pycld3-0.20` and execute `./venv/Scripts/python.exe setup.py build`)

I managed to successfully `build` pycld3 but was unable to `isntall` -- got some `ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980` error when I tried `venv/Scripts/python setup.py install`.

Please accept my answer if it fixes your `'google/protobuf/port_def.inc': No such file or directory` problem:).