# How to properly link third party library (like protobuf) into Qt Creator project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, protocol-buffers, qmake

I have succesfully managed to build Protobuf on WIndows XP using MSYS 1.0 (`C:\msys\`) and MinGW from Qt 5.2 bundle (`C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\`) following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243816/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw).

The result is that I have following 8 files in `C:\msys\local\lib`

- libprotobuf-8.dll (7,9MB)
- libprotobuf-lite-8.dll (0,9MB)
- libprotobuf-lite.a(1,1MB)
- libprotobuf-lite.dll.a (0,3MB)
- libprotobuf-lite.la (1KB)
- libprotobuf.a (10,3MB)
- libprotobuf.dll.a (2MB)
- libprotobuf.la (1KB)

Which is the correct file I need to include in my Qt project, where to place it and how to properly link it (there are three choices in "Include library wizard" in Qt Creator). What would be the best practice ?

Comment: Despite my answer, protobuf is old an unmaintained. I would suggest looking into capnproto.

Comment: I have to use protobuf because of compatibility with another application. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: @lpapp  you may be mistaken.  Release 3.14.0 (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.14.0) Nov. 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
LIBS += -lprotobuf ...
```

etc. I would place the dlls next your binary if they are only used by your project.

Comment: That is what I tried as first, unfortunately it didn't work. But I have already figured it out. You have to copy headers from msys/local/include and libs from  msys/local/lib into Qt\...\mingw\local and lib. Then it works.

Comment: @Kousalik: works for me. Moreover, you are supposed to provide everything you have ever tried not to waste others' time.

Comment: I'm sorry. What am I doing wrong ? When I follow the above mentioned protobuf build steps then I get Error: google/protobuf/stubs/common.h: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>. Everything is fine when I manualy copy related files from msys /lib;/include into MinGWs /lib;/include. Then it works fine but that step isn't mentioned anywhere. I thought that the --prefix=`cd /mingw; pwd -W` should do this work but it does not.

Comment: And that helps how ? This error came from my project where the linking according to your answer is done. Forgive me, I'm just trying to get the bigger picture. I'm not much experienced in C++ development, especially on Windows.