# Interrupt/Exception caught using Make while installing Protocol Buffer

Tags: path, makefile, protocol-buffers

I have been looking for the solution to this problem for months now but nothing has solved the issue so I would greatly appreciate anyone's help.

I am trying to install the Protocol Buffer (protobuf) version 2.5 on Windows 8 and while following the instructions

> $ ./configure
>
> $ make
>
> $ make check
>
> $ make install

I keep running into this error when I try "make"

```
C:\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x4227dc)
```

I have read of multiple people experiencing the same problem (http://hdrlab.org.nz/articles/windows-development/make-interrupt-exception-caught-code-0xc00000fd-addr-0x4217b/) and have fixed both my directories and path. My current path looks like

> C:\GnuWin32\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;

I also placed the protobuf folder in

> C:\protobuf-2.5.0

in a desperate attempt but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you re-run configure after changing the paths? At what point does make crash?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes I did re-run configure and it crashes the instant I run "make". I'm not sure how I can copy and paste code from Git Bash but the only output I get from running "make" is the error posted.

Comment: Right-click the titlebar -> Edit -> Mark. Then left-click and drag to select a square region. With a region selected right-click to copy the region.

Comment: @EtanReisner 

`$ make

c:\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe: Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0x4227d3)`

this is what I see

Comment: have you looked at the output of `make -d`?

Comment: @user657267 This happened after using `make -d` `This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
find_and_set_shell °æ·I A½≫oAI default_shell = C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe A¸·I(·I) ¼¼ÆACO´I´U.`

and a lot more gibberish and at the end

`Unhandled exception filter called from program c:\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe
ExceptionCode = c00000fd
ExceptionFlags = 0
ExceptionAddress = 4227d3
make: write error`

I'm running a 64 bit laptop. Is that the problem? Did I download a wrong version?

Comment: @Platypi what language is your OS in?

Comment: @user657267 The System Locale is set in Korean right now but everything else in English. Do I need to change that to English first?

Comment: @Platypi If any of the paths you use has Korean characters this might be causing your issue.

Comment: @user657267 I've read through my entire path multiple times now to check for errors and no Korean letters exist. Any other ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67225/discussion-between-platypi-and-user657267).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the Protocol Buffer by downloading MSYS and downloading a FRESH tar.gz file version of protobuf-2.5.0.

The instructions I found were from the top answer from this post:

[How to build Google's protobuf in Windows using MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243816/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw)

Good luck to anyone else needing this!