# Protobuf 3.0.0-alpha-1 not compiling on windows

Tags: c++, mingw, protocol-buffers, msys

I'm trying to compile protobuf 3.0.0 alpha 1 on Windows using MinGW 4.9.2 & MSYS.

According to the instructions I'm supposed to:

```
./configure 
make
make check
make install
```

I added `--prefix=/c/path/to/mingw to configure` ([How to build Google's protobuf in Windows using MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243816/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw)) but it didnt help.

It fails at `make` with the message:

> CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /home/Markus/protobuf-3.0.0-alpha-
>   1/missing aclocal-1.14 -I m4
>
> /home/Markus/protobuf-3.0.0-alpha-1/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.14: command not
>   found
>
> WARNING: 'aclocal-1.14' is missing on your system.
>
> ```
>     You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
>      'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
>      The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
>      <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
>      It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
>      <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
>      <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
>      <http://www.perl.org/>
> ```
>
> make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127

I've tried installing Automake but it doesnt come with aclocal.

Also today at work i managed to get it working on the first try with a bare MinGW & MSYS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to install autoconf (which is separate from automake, though they are often used together). You may also need to install libtool.

Comment: Didnt really work that easy for me because somehow my mingw didnt like autoconf.

I ended up using cygwin for compiling protobuf but at least it works now.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by "MinGW didn't like autoconf"? autoconf is one of the main things that MSYS is intended to run, so it should work. On another note, if you are compiling from a release package, then autoconf/automake/libtool/etc. is not supposed to be required (since it comes with the package), so you might want to file a bug against protobufs.

Comment: When running make after configure in MSYS it kept spamming a few thousand lines of empty 'autom4te: ' (nothing else after that just 'autom4te' and ended with an error. Happend to various versions i tested including the latest. About not being required: thats the weird thing. I didnt need it on my PC at work but both on my notebook and private PC it failed without. I also found a binary package of autoconf that works with MSYS now.

Comment: @Shyro So, the build will re-run autotools if it thinks the files are out-of-date. If it worked on one computer and failed on another, perhaps the problem is simply the clock. Is the clock set wrong on the computer where it failed?

Comment: Actually it failed on two systems and only worked on one. The clock is set correctly on all of them. I cant think of any difference that would have an impact on it.

Comment: I came across this issue too. The fix for me was to use Cygwin and make sure that I had the Automake 1.14 package installed (it's under "devel" package or something in the Cygwin package installation menu). That's the easiest way to get the binaries for it on Windows I think. Anyways, it compiled fine after that.